# How to use Component class in JSF2 using JSP

Tags: jsf-2

Is there any way to write custom tags using components and renderers in JSF2.0 using JSP?
could you please send the example if it is possible.

Comment: Apart from the concrete question, are you well aware that JSP is deprecated as JSF view technology since december 2009?

Comment: Yes but we can use JSPs in JSF2. and we are doing migration to JSF2 and keeping existing JSPs as it is in new application also. but i struched up at custom component classes, how we can use in this application